# How to set specific css value for javaFX ProgressBar during Runtime?

Tags: css, javafx, progress-bar, background-size

I have usual CSS for my `ProgressBar`:

```css
.progress-bar > .track {
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.progress-bar > .bar {
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
  -fx-background-image: url('/images/progress_bar.png');
  -fx-background-size: 1600px 50px;
  -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Image `progress_bar.png` is 3-colored bar that changes from green to red as it reaches it's end. It works nicely when application is run.

My problem are those hard coded values for background size. This work on full HD  displays perfectly but on 1366x768 most of yellow/red parts are cut out. I would like to set this property during run-time to match screen size. Is this possible?

I tried to use `setStyle()` method in `ProgressBar` but without success. Maybe I am just doing it wrong so if anyone has working example...

I also tried to set width to 100% (instead of px) but that does not work either. It just shows compressed bar and then it stretches it to 100% width.

Here is image: [image: progress_bar.png]

Comment: Can you post some images of what you're trying to achieve? It may be that you can do this using, e.g. a linear gradient, in a way that is independent of the size.

Comment: OK, I attached image. Have in mind that customers want it exactly like this. You know, design decisions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using CSS alone. However a customized `Skin` could be used that replaces the `bar` `Node` with a `ImageView` and uses the `bar` as clip instead:

#### `progress.BarBackgroundProgressBarSkin`

```
public class BarBackgroundProgressBarSkin extends ProgressBarSkin {

    public BarBackgroundProgressBarSkin(ProgressBar control) {
        super(control);
    }

    private ImageView barBackground;

    @Override
    protected void initialize() {
        super.initialize();

        barBackground = new ImageView();

        barBackground.setManaged(false);

        barBackground.setPreserveRatio(false);
        barBackground.getStyleClass().setAll("bar-background");
        int barIndex;

        List<Node> children = getChildren();
        int size = children.size();

        for (barIndex = 0; barIndex < size && !children.get(barIndex).getStyleClass().contains("bar"); barIndex++) {
        }

        Region bar = (Region) children.set(barIndex, barBackground);
        barBackground.setClip(bar);

        // fill the bar for clipping
        bar.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.WHITE, new CornerRadii(2), new Insets(3, 3, 4, 3))));
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
        // set pos
        barBackground.setLayoutX(x);
        barBackground.setLayoutY(y);

        // set size
        barBackground.setFitHeight(h);
        barBackground.setFitWidth(w);

        super.layoutChildren(x, y, w, h);
    }

}
```

#### style.css

```css
.progress-bar {
    -fx-skin: 'progress.BarBackgroundProgressBarSkin';
}

.progress-bar > .bar-background {
    /* your image goes here */
    -fx-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/glUAd.png');
}

.progress-bar > .track {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

#### Demo

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(progressBar);
    progressBar.setPrefSize(300, 18);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);

    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

    Timeline tl = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(progressBar.progressProperty(), 0d)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), new KeyValue(progressBar.progressProperty(), 1d, Interpolator.EASE_OUT))
    );

    tl.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    tl.play();

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```